# Can't convert function pointer argument

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, v8

The error I'm getting:

```
error C2664: 'v8::FunctionTemplate::New' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'v8::Handle<T> (__cdecl *)(const v8::Arguments &)' to 'v8::InvocationCallback'
```

Relevant definitions:

```
typedef Handle<Value> (*InvocationCallback)(const Arguments& args);




template<class C> class V8ScriptClass
{
public:
    template<class C, typename Rtype, typename Ptype1, Rtype (C::*FuncPtr)(Ptype1)> 
    void RegisterFunc(const char* const scriptname)
    {
        objtemplate->Set(
            v8::String::New(scriptname), 
            v8::FunctionTemplate::New(
            V8ScriptClass<C>::RelayCallback<C, Rtype, Ptype1, FuncPtr>
                ));
    };

template<typename Rtype, typename Ptype1, Rtype (*FuncPtr)(Ptype1 param1)>
static v8::Handle<v8::Value> RelayCallback(const v8::Arguments& args)
{
    std::cerr<<__FUNCTION__<<std::endl;
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope;
    return handle_scope.Close(toJSType( ((FuncPtr)(toCType(args[0]))) ));
};
```

Looks to me like the typedef and the actual function signature are identical.

edit: forgot one declaration:

```
class EXPORT FunctionTemplate : public Template {
 public:
  /** Creates a function template.*/
  static Local<FunctionTemplate> New(
      InvocationCallback callback = 0,
      Handle<Value> data = Handle<Value>(),
      Handle<Signature> signature = Handle<Signature>());
```

Comment: Where are you using InvocationCallback?

Comment: added the missing declaration

Comment: Not just the signature (=0 is a default argument) but the actual invocation.

Comment: look inside RegisterFunc, it's the FunctionTemplate::New constructor which takes a function pointer argument

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error? At the point of instantiation i.e. where you are using RegisterFunc? Otherwise, looks like the compiler is confused. Can you try with a typename? The RelayCallback is still of incomplete type in RegisterFunc.

Comment: Just for test, try explicitly accept this function tpye instead typedef. What compiller says?

Comment: @heeen: Can you simplify your code?

Comment: We can not just copy and paste that code into a source file. So trying to find the problem is next to imposable. Post code that can be compiled and generate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. the RelayCallback template takes a static function pointer as argument, and I tried to instantiate it with a member function pointer. I just had to change it to a member function pointer template argument.